# Pusblishing to topic problem (Mavros)

Tags: ros, mavros, topic, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to push to the override RC for mavros.

I checked the message type first
rostopic type mavros/rc/override
giving
mavros_msgs/OverrideRCIn

I then check the parameters for this message type
rosmsg show mavros_msgs/OverrideRCIn
giving
uint16 CHAN_RELEASE=0
uint16 CHAN_NOCHANGE=65535
uint16[8] channels

however, when I try to publish with
rostopic pub /mavros/rc/override mavros/OverrideRCIn "channels:[1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1325, 1560, 2000, 1500]"
it gives the following error
ERROR: invalid message type: mavros/OverrideRCIn.
If this is a valid message type, perhaps you need to type 'rosmake mavros'

am I passing the arguments wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223040/pusblishing-to-topic-problem-(mavros)/) by [harewei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22569/harewei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`mavros/` != `mavros_msgs/`!

Also check [rc_io docs](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros#mavros.2BAC8-Plugins.Subscribed_Topics-1).

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harewei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22569/harewei/) on 2015-12-24**:
right, stupid me for missing that...thanks!